# Javascript how to compare hash special character

Tags: javascript, jquery

How i can compare hash (#) character in javascript or JQuery ?

I have variable with text "ABC #:" now i want to compare if another variable has same text.

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So you are trying to compare strings?

Comment: If you are just comparing strings you should just be able to say if (string1 === string2) { --doStuff-- }

Comment: @Taplar:  let locationContent = $(this).text();
    if (locationContent == 'ABC #:')

Comment: @HashTag that's valid.  I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: @Robert its not working i think we have to escape # character... all other comparisons are working without # character.

Comment: @Taplar this is not working. i think # cannot be compare like that.

Comment: Sure it can.  # is not a special character in strings in javascript.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q9trhbnj/  works just fine

Comment: Maybe there is another issue at play here. Can you post a snippet of code that does not work?

Answer (score 1):

Some string comparison examples in JavaScript:

```js
const val1 = 'ABC #:';
const val2 = 'CDE';
const val3 = 'ABC #:';

console.log(val1 === val3); // true
console.log(val1 === val2); // false
console.log(val1.includes('ABC #:')); // true
```

Hopefully these will clarify. As long as # is in a string, you shouldn't need to escape anything.